# JavaFX under Mac OS X: System-Menu and modal windows

Tags: macos, javafx, menu, modal-dialog

I am currently facing a problem with JavaFX menus under Mac OS X and modal dialogs.

I am using the method

```
MenuBar.setUseSystemMenuBar(true)
```

in order to use the system menu bar for my application menu. This works fine but the menu is not blocked in case a modal dialog is open. Even using

```
initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL)
```

does not block access to the menu. Find below my small example:

```
public class MyApp extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        // scene
        BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
        Scene scene = new Scene(borderPane);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        // menu
        MenuBar menuBar = new MenuBar();
        Menu file = new Menu("File");
        MenuItem open = new MenuItem("Open");
        open.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                FileChooser fileDialog = new FileChooser();
                fileDialog.showOpenDialog(primaryStage);
            }
        });
        file.getItems().add(open);
        Menu options = new Menu("Options");
        MenuItem uioptions = new MenuItem("UI Options");
        options.getItems().add(uioptions);
        Menu help = new Menu("Help");
        MenuItem about = new MenuItem("About");
        help.getItems().add(about);
        menuBar.getMenus().addAll(file, options, help);
        borderPane.setTop(menuBar);
        menuBar.setUseSystemMenuBar(true);
        // popup
        Button button = new Button("Click for Pop-up Window");
        Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION);
        alert.setTitle("Information Dialog");
        alert.setHeaderText("Look, an Information Dialog");
        alert.setContentText("I have a great message for you!");
        alert.initOwner(primaryStage);
        alert.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        button.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                alert.showAndWait();
            }
        });
        borderPane.setBottom(button);
        // show scene
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

What I did observe is that removing the line

```
alert.initOwner(primaryStage);
```

from my example removes the menu from my application when the dialog opens. But I do not think this is the right way.

I think that this behaviour of Java FX menus under Mac OS X might designed by intention as all Mac OS programs show the same behaviour. Their menus are never disabled but the dialogs are alway non-modal.

What is the correct way (may be according to Apples philosophy with menus and dialogs)? Are there any workarounds or better solutions available?

Answer (score 1):

I have found a workaround (or solution?) for the issue now. I have created a method to enable / disable the menus now:

```
    public void setMenuEnabled(boolean enable) {
    ObservableList<Menu> menus = menuBar.getMenus();
    for (Menu menu : menus)
        menu.setVisible(enable);
}
```

For every modal dialog I do invoke the method first to disable the menus, show the dialog after that und enable the menus finally again.

```
    setMenuEnabled(false);
    mydialog.showAndWait();
    setMenuEnabled(true);
```

And yes, I have extended the classes for my modal dialogs like Stage or Dialog and added code to disable / enable menus automatically:

```
public ModalStage extends Stage {
   private MyController myController;

   public ModalStage(MyController myController) {
        this.myController = myController;
        addEventHandler(WindowEvent.WINDOW_SHOWN, new EventHandler<WindowEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(WindowEvent window) {
            myController.setMenuEnabled(false);
        }
    });
    addEventHandler(WindowEvent.WINDOW_HIDDEN, new EventHandler<WindowEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(WindowEvent window) {
            myController.setMenuEnabled(true);
        }
    });
}
```

Maybe there are better solutions to my question but currently I do not know any other ;)